# Unable to preview media items

Tags: media, wysiwyg, 9

I have a node page where, in the WYSIWYG, I have embedded about 50 media items. When I edit the node, I can see this error for some of the media items.

> An error occurred while trying to preview the media. Please save your work and reload this page.

In the browser console, the error is the following.

> mysite.com/media/wysiwyg/preview?text=%3Cdrupal-media%20data-entity-type%3D%22media%22%20data-entity-uuid%3D%22b21db71d-3c53-4d46-afed-a3197767fac4%22%20data-href%3D%22%22%20data-size%3D%22original-size%22%3E%3C%2Fdrupal-media%3E&uuid=b21db71d-3c53-4d46-afed-a3197767fac4 429

429 is the status code.

> [image: screenshot]

Is there any limit for the number of the embedded media?
How do I get rid of these errors?

Answer (score 0):

429 is the HTTP status code for "Too Many Requests". Drupal would not be responsible for serving a 429; something in your server infrastructure would do that, like a load balancer or Apache/nginx. Given that, this might be out of scope for Drupal Answers.